# Get specific key-value from Hashicorp secret engine version 2

Tags: curl, key-value, hashicorp-vault, hashicorp

I'm using Hashicorp engine version 2 and namespace `vault-poc`

Displays all key values for engine `kv` and path `tool-common/dev` as below:

```
C:\Users\meuser>curl -H "X-Vault-Token: s.lcF5f0npjzeioNnbJvPVjihN" -H "X-Vault-Namespace: vault-poc/" -X GET https://so-vlt.mybank.com/v1/kv/data/tool-common/dev

{"request_id":"2fa8ea3f-d381-59c4-4306-78fc9c7d1578","lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":0,"data":{"data":{"svc-DeployDev":"5!KaA1UvST8d","svc-DeployProd":"NjPC14rDJvc"},"metadata":{"created_time":"2023-06-06T17:45:20.449956832Z","deletion_time":"","destroyed":false,"version":2}},"wrap_info":null,"warnings":null,"auth":null}
```

Unable to get a single specific key value i.e `svc-DeployProd`:

```
C:\Users\meuser>curl -H "X-Vault-Token: s.lcF5f0npjzeioNnbJvPVjihN" -H "X-Vault-Namespace: vault-poc/" -X GET https://so-vlt.mybank.com/v1/kv/data/tool-common/dev/data/svc-DeployProd

{"errors":[]}
```

I'm on Windows. How can I get hashicorp to return a specific key-value i.e `svc-DeployProd`?

Also, the desired output should be like the below without the junk data [probably json]:

```
"svc-DeployProd":"NjPC14rDJvc"
```

Comment: That response structure in the question is for KV version 2.

Comment: Thank you @MattSchuchard I correct the same in my post

Comment: I see that no one else has commented on this, so just to let you know this is a question about JSON parsing of `stdout` on the Windows platform. I would recommend searching for documentation on that in Powershell, `jq`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the parsing problem @Matt Schuchard mentionned in the comments, you must structure your data when you store it in Vault.

In other words, Vault will not interpret the data you stored under `tool-common/dev` and see if it can extract `svc-DeployProd` or `data/svc-DeployProd` from the JSON it happens to store there. It will also make your life much easier   when you will write access policies if the path to your secret has some meaning.

So to solve your problem, you must write your secrets like this (assuming [`VAULT_NAMESPACE`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/commands#vault_namespace), [`VAULT_ADDR`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/commands#vault_addr) and [`VAULT_TOKEN`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/commands#vault_token) are set in the environment):

```
vault kv put kv/tool-common/dev/svc-DeployDev 'username=somehting' 'password=5!KaA1UvST8d'
vault kv put kv/tool-common/dev/svc-DeployProd 'username=something' 'password=NjPC14rDJvc'
```

Notice that you can still store rich data that way. Here I stored a username along with the password.

To get the data back just ask for it:

```
vault kv get --field password kv/tool-common/dev/svc-DeployDev
```

Will return `5!KaA1UvST8d` parsed and ready to go.

With that in hand, ask Vault to provide you with the cURL command by adding `--output-curl-string`:

```
$ vault kv get -output-curl-string --field password kv/tool-common/dev/svc-DeployDev
```

But you are on your own to parse. The whole thing should look like this in the end:

```
$ curl --silent --header "X-Vault-Token: $(vault print token)" http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/kv/data/tool-common/dev/svc-DeployDev | jq -r .data.data.password
5!KaA1UvST8d
```